# Adding Checkboxs into angular js Accordion

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I am trying to add check boxes into a particular scope.group

Below is the mock-up of what i want to achieve and code.

[image]

```
 <accordion close-others="false">

    <accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" is-open="group.open">
        <accordion-heading>
            <i ng-class="{'icon-minus-sign':groups[$index].open,'icon-plus-sign':!groups[$index].open }"></i>
            <span class="title-pos" >{{group.title}}</span>
        </accordion-heading>
        {{group.content}}


     </accordion-group>

  </accordion>

     <script>


        angular.module('main',['ui.bootstrap'])
          .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){

          $scope.groups = [
            {
              "title":"Series",

              "open":true
            },
            {
              "title":"Price Range",
              "content":"Content B",
              "open":true
            },
            {
              "title":"Engine Type",
              "content":"Content C",
              "open":false
            },
             {
              "title":"Engine Type",
              "content":"Content C",
              "open":false
            },
             {
              "title":"Life Style",
              "content":"Content C",
              "open":false
            },
             {
              "title":"Seats",
              "content":"Content C",
              "open":false
            },
            ];

        })


      </script>
```

I would like to add the check box to Engine type group.
Look forward for any help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Replace `{{group.content}}` with `<div ng-bind-html="group.content"></div>`

You should then add your checkboxes HTML code inside `"content"` part of "Engine Type" group, similar to this :

```
...
{
    "title":"Engine Type",
    "content":'<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="Petrol">Petrol',
    "open":false
},
...
```

For each one of the enteries in `$scope.groups` whatever comes in `"content"` will appear inside `<div ng-bind-html="group.content"></div>` block.

Finally, Be sure to add `ngSanitize` to your module dependencies as in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aA7bXYmRrDIolNvGYjdU?p=preview)

Comment: It is better to avoid having view defined in the data, not to mention you'll need to repeat `<input type="checkbox"...` for every line of data.

Comment: @Icycool What would be the reason to avoid having HTML code in data?

Comment: It'll be easier to organize if we put all HTML inside one place, in addition to having access of tools like `ng-repeat` and variable interpolation. But it's not a hard rule, though. In some cases we need to construct HTML in a directive and then add to the element.

Comment: @Icycool I wouldn't call it a better approach. This is just a matter of situation. If the front-end developer doesn't have access to change the json response structure in the backend (which is necessary for your solution above), a reasonable approach would be just to add the HTML in the content. Besides, it's hard to find texts with no HTML tag (which you called 'view' in your comment). Also, I don't see any harm in repeating an input tag 3 times if this is not going to be a pattern in the data.

Comment: A situation where using your approach is good that I can think of is when the backend returns the input tag itself, due to a legacy system returning a partial view. Other than that, I would imagine the backend returns the array of `["Petrol", "Diesel", "Hybrid"]` in an array or an array of object, then it is much easier to use that array directly than string append them into the input tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the checkboxes in the content area

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" is-open="group.open">
    <accordion-heading>
        <i ng-class="{'icon-minus-sign':groups[$index].open,'icon-plus-sign':!groups[$index].open }"></i>
        <span class="title-pos" >{{group.title}}</span>
    </accordion-heading>
    <div ng-repeat="option in group.options">
        <!-- checkbox and text here -->
    </div>
 </accordion-group>
```

And reorganize your data to include the checkboxes model

```
$scope.groups = [
    {
       "title":"Engine Type",
       "content":"Content C",
       "open":false,
       "options": [
           "Petrol", // or if you have id for them: {id:engine_petrol, name:"Petrol"}
           "Diesel",
           "Hybrid"
       ]
    }
];
```